# Listing existing files that are not present in a list using shell

Tags: shell, xargs

How do I list files that exist, but not present in the list? More specifically, I'd like to remove `*.cpp` files not listed in `Build`. Something like this lists files that **are** present in both the current directory and the `Build` file:

```
ls *.cpp | xargs -I % bash -c 'grep % Build'
```

However, the following line is incorrect of course:

```
ls *.cpp | xargs -I % bash -c 'grep -v % Build'
```

Thus the question: how does one list the `*.cpp` files that are **not** present in the `Build` file using shell commands? I can do something like this, bug this is ugly:

```
ls *.cpp | perl -e 'while(<>){chomp;my $l=`grep $_ Build`;chomp $l;if(length $l==0){print("rm $_\n");}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

> More specifically, I'd like to remove *.cpp files not listed in Build

You want `comm` or `join` to join two sorted lists together. I always mix `comm` arguments, but I think:

```
comm -23 <(find . -type f -name '*.cpp' | sort) <(sort Build) |
xargs -n '\n' echo rm
```

or if you want to depend on filename expansion:

```
shopt -s nullglob  # at least
comm -23 <(printf "%s\n" *.cpp | sort) <(sort Build) | ...
```

[Do not parse `ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).

The `<(...)` is bash specific process substitution. In non-bash shell just create a temporary file with the output of processes.

Answer (score 0):

GNU `grep` already offers you this possibility with the `-f` switch:

```
printf '%s\n' *.cpp | grep -F -x -v -f Build
```

- `-F`: no regex
- `-x`: full-line match
- `-v`: invert (not match)
- `-f`: any of the line in Build

In other words: filter out any line in Build